# My Gaussian 2D template is not returning the correct values

Tags: java, image-processing, gaussian

I am writing a piece of java code that given a width, height and sigma value will return a 2D Gaussian template that I will then be able to convolve with another image.

Here is the Gaussian 2D equation:

[image]

Now I am simplyfying this to something like this. We can divide this in 2 parts, the one with the Pi and the E.

So in my code I have this:

```
piProduct = Math.pow(2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(sigma,2), -1);
```

And for the E part I again divide in 2 parts (base and exponent):

```
eulerNumberProductExponent = (Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2)) / (2 * Math.pow(sigma,2));
```

and the base (with the exponent):

```
eulerNumberProduct = Math.pow(Math.E, -1*eulerNumberProductExponent);
```

Now all I have to do is to multiply the Pi part with the E part:

```
coefficient = piProduct * eulerNumberProduct;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
public double[][] getGaussianTemplate(int width, int height, double sigma){
    double[][] gaussianTemplate = new double [height][width];
    double coefficient;
    double piProduct;
    double eulerNumberProductExponent;
    double eulerNumberProduct;

    piProduct = Math.pow(2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(sigma,2), -1);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            eulerNumberProductExponent = (Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2)) / (2 * Math.pow(sigma,2));
            eulerNumberProduct = Math.pow(Math.E, -1*eulerNumberProductExponent);
            coefficient = piProduct * eulerNumberProduct;

            gaussianTemplate[y][x] = coefficient;
            System.out.println("At x: "+x+" and y: "+y+" the coefficient is: "+coefficient);
        }
    }

    printTemplate(gaussianTemplate,width,height);

    return gaussianTemplate;
}
```

Now this is what I am getting for sigma = 0.1:

```
 | 15.915494 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
```

Which is what `printTemplate(gaussianTemplate,width,height);` prints.

According to the book I am following for a 5x5 template with a sigma of 0.1 I should get this:

[image]

What is wrong in the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually filters are calculated from the center out

```
for (int x = -width/2; x <= width/2; x++) {
    for (int y = -height/2; y <= height/2; y++) {
        eulerNumberProductExponent = (Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2)) / (2 * Math.pow(sigma,2));
        eulerNumberProduct = Math.pow(Math.E, -1*eulerNumberProductExponent);
        coefficient = piProduct * eulerNumberProduct;
//            gaussianTemplate[y][x] = coefficient;
        System.out.println("At x: "+x+" and y: "+y+" the coefficient is: "+coefficient);
    }
}
```

This will give you a symmetrical filter around the center. What the book says and what calculates are unknown.

Comment: "Usually filters are calculated from the center out", could you please elaborate ?

Comment: If check this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html, point (8), you mean use something similar like that one? Starts from -4 to 4 ?

Comment: yes indeed (0, 0) is at the center, the hightest value attained there